# How can I crop the text in the center on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need do truncate `overflow.ellipsis` text in centre, with always visible id text in the end, like this

```
Really, Really Long 
Compa... ID 0000001
```

I try do it by `RichText` like this

```
          valueWidget: RichText(
            maxLines: 2,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: '${organisation.displayName} Really, '
                      'Really Long Company Name',
                  style: theme
                      .textTheme(textColor: theme.secondary.defaultColor.value)
                      .headline5?.copyWith(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: ' GB ${organisation.id}',
                  style: theme
                      .textTheme(textColor: theme.neutral.dark1Color.value)
                      .headline5?.copyWith(overflow: TextOverflow.visible),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

but it do not work as I expected. how I can do this right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Row` widget with the company name part wrapped into an `Expanded` widget. This way the id will be displayed completely, and the rest of the available space will be occupied by the name. If the name is longer than the remaining space, it will end with the ellipsis.

(If the total space available is not enough for the id, you will get an error.)

For example see this `SizedBox`:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        child: Row(children: const [
          Expanded(
              child: Text('Company Company Company Company Company Company',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)),
          Text('ID 00000001')
        ]));
  }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I need more then one row, like in my example 2 rows.

Comment: If you add `maxLines: 2` to the company name `Text` widget, you will have two lines, but not the way that is in your question: the `ID` will be something like a second column.

Comment: You can also add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end`  to the `Row` widget to display `ID` at the bottom, but if you want the first line to expand until the end of `ID`, that could be complicated, I'm afraid I can't help you out on that.